# Inject JavaScript/CSS on specific/wildcard urls via Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I've seen similar questions on here, but none really answered my questions...

1. How to check if the url matches a string. This part would be easy, but there's a catch... I need a wildcard: e.g. " **google.com/search*** " where it would trigger no matter what comes after "search".
2. How to then apply that idea to a Firefox add-on WITHOUT using any XUL (it seems the only thing add-on tutorials teach you is how to deal with XUL add-ons ffs). All I want to do is inject my personal JS/CSS into these pages without having to deal with anything overly complicated.

Chrome makes this stupidly easy to do via the manifest, but I have very limited knowledge of Firefox addon development (and JavaScript in general, actually). Any links that could help me would be great too; I don't mind reading, I just need to know WHERE to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Firefox Add-SDK? Or doing pure bootstrap addon?

If you are using add-sdk its incredibly easy as well.

```
var contentScriptString = '$("body").html("<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>");';

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScript: contentScriptString,
  contentScriptFile: data.url("jquery.js")
});
```

This will match anything that ends with `*.mozilla.org`

So you would do `include: "http://www.google.com/search*"`

Read all about the dumbed down pattern matching used in add-on sdk which is still pretty powerful: [MDN :: Add-on SDK - Modifying Web Pages Based on URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL)

Comment: That link is exactly what I've been looking for. I searched Google/Bing for _HOURS_ looking for a page containing even a sliver of that info and got nothing. Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure :) It's off the front page of the addon-sdk hub page you'll probably like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK :)

Answer (score 1):

You need [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to determine if that string is contained within your search.

```
if (-1 !== 'google.com/search/oreo') {
    console.log("Jackpot");
}
```

However this will trigger even when the string is somewhere else in your string, like:

```
if (-1 !== 'https://unrlelated.domain.com/blog/google.com/search/oreo') {
    console.log("False alert");
}
```

For more control, you need [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
if (null !== /^http(s?):\/\/(www\.)?google\.com\/search/i) {
    console.log("Yay, it starts with google.com!");
}
```

For injecting something between you might use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). As for how, I'll leave it as an exercise

As you might've seen I've linked mdn a few times. It's great resource, all you have to do is to google "mdn keyword" and you'll have almost the best explanation there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the other one had the exact link I've been searching for! You were right though, MDN is the place to go haha